# Nullable parameter in C++/CLI not appearing in XML documentation for C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

Here is an example of the problem. This is the implementation of a static method Add defined within a class foo.

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds two or three numbers together.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x">First number</param>
/// <param name="y">Second number</param>
/// <param name="z">Third number - optional - defaults to 0 if set to null.</param>
System::Double foo::Add(
    System::Double x,
    System::Double y,
    System::Nullable<System::Double> z)
{
  System::Double output = x + y;
  if (z.HasValue)
    output = output + z.Value;
  return output;
}
```

I have used /doc when compiling this code fragment using C++ with the /clr option.
Subsequently xdcmake is used to produce an XML file.
The XML file looks OK - the automatic description of the parameters looks like this:

Add(System.Double,System.Double,System.Nullable`1{System.Double})

followed by the summary and param tags defined in the code above.

However when I use the resulting .NET assembly within C# (Visual Studio 2010) I don't see any documentation for this function in the Object Browser (the entire function has no documentation, not just the nullable parameter z).

For functions without nullable inputs there is no problem and I see the list of parameters and summary in the Object Browser as I would have hoped.

Any ideas about what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: I have same problem, but in your case you might work around it using:
Add(double x, double y,
[System::Runtime::InteropServices::Optional] double z);
which generates method with optional parameter z defaulting to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem today. From looking at the C# manual via http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029 I saw that xdcmake was generating the wrong XML for nullable parameters. The `1 was not required.

The XML entry for the Add function with a nullable parameter should be:

Add(System.Double,System.Double,System.Nullable{System.Double})

instead. Quote from the manual (from section A.3.1 of the C# language specification version 5.0):

> Arguments that refer to constructed generic types are encoded using
>   the generic type, followed by “{“, followed by a comma-separated list
>   of type arguments, followed by “}”.